# end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector xxxxxxxxx

Tags: linux, raid, hard-drive, kernel

I have a IBM server. This server contains 3 hard disk with RAID 5. It was working fine earlier. Unfortunately this machine got the following error message.  After that I have rebooted the systems. After that I am getting the following error message in kern.log and demsg

> kernel: [65896.678870] end_request: I/O error,
>   dev sda, sector 17430271
>    kernel: [69263.783957]
>   sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK
>   driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE,SUGGEST_OK :
>   [69263.783957] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current]
>   kernel: [69263.783957] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Add.
>   Sense: Internal target failure

Whether it is kernel problem or hard disk problem or Raid problem

Comment: It might be a dust problem too. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1047221/446253 for a case of this

Answer (score 2):

If looks like hard drive prpblem to me.

Your hard disk sda, which I believe is the first hard drive, is having errors.
Replacing the hard drive should fix this issue.